# Is there a way to split/factor out common parts of Gradle build

Tags: gradle, build

We have several independent builds (each independent build is a multi-project build). The main build scripts have become quite big as we have a set of common tasks reused by subprojects. There is also a lot of repetition between independent builds. What we are looking for is:

1. A way to split the main build file
   into smaller files
2. A way to reuse some parts of the
   build in other independent builds

What is the best way to achieve this in Gradle?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Gradle 0.9 allows you to import a build script from another build script. Have a look at: [Configuring the project using an external build script](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:configuring_using_external_script). Basically it's `apply from: 'other.gradle'`.

One thing the user guide doesn't mention is that the 'from' parameter can be a URL, so you can make your shared scripts available via HTTP somewhere (eg your subversion repository), and import them from multiple builds.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you think 0.8 supports that feature?

Comment: No, it's a new feature in 0.9

Comment: grrrr, link was broken, need to dig on my own now.

Comment: this seems to work for now.. http://gradle.org/docs/0.9/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:configuring_using_external_script

Comment: Link for 1.0: http://gradle.org/docs/1.0/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:configuring_using_external_script

Comment: ```apply from: 'other.gradle'```

Comment: I imported a file with some common functions in it, but I can't call the functions

Comment: I found that this is a very nice solution http://saulmm.github.io/squeezing-gradle-builds/

Comment: @box that link is broken now

Comment: @GreenGiant Thank you for noticing - this should work http://saulmm.github.io/squeezing-gradle-builds

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you.

Comment: `apply from:` and then what? How do I use this thing with `dependsOn`.

Comment: @Gavriel I finally managed it. 
example:
ext.repo = {
    it.repositories {
        maven {
            name 'proxy'
            url 'http://nexus.pagseguro.intranet/repository/public/'
        }
    }
}
and use it like this: (after the apply from)
buildscript rootProject.ext.repo

Comment: apply from doesn't allow me to have plugins {} in the included file

Comment: @Gavriel Use `apply plugin:` in the included file.

`plugins {}` is just an optimisation for resolving needed plugins before running the build. It is sad tho that Gradle doesn't allow to use it in multifile structure.

Answer (score 42):

The solution I found implies mapping the things you have in your `other.gradle` file.

```
def getVersionName = { testParam ->
    println "${testParam}"

    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
ext{
    VERConsts = [:]
    VERConsts['NAME'] = getVersionName("test param")
    VERConsts['NAME_CALL'] = getVersionName
}
```

Then, in your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply from: 'other.gradle'
// ...
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionName VERConsts['NAME_CALL']("test param")
        // or
        versionName VERConsts['NAME']
    }
}
```

Then, the `versionName` will have the call result.

**Notes**:

- `VERConsts['NAME'] = getVersionName()` will call `getVersionName()` and store its result. Using it in your script e.g. `versionName VERConsts['NAME']` will then assign the stored value.
- `VERConsts['NAME_CALL']` will instead store a reference to the function. Using `VERConsts['NAME_CALL']()` in your script will actually call the function and assign the result to your variable

The former will result in the same value being assigned across the script while the latter may result in different values (e.g. if someone pushes another version while your script is running).

Comment: I actually found this more useful than the other answer for sharing build script helper methods between projects.

Comment: This answer was the most helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: can you give non-android example? what is versionName VERConsts['NAME_CALL']()? how to run it in clean java gradle project?

Comment: Im trying to use this other.gradle apply logic.  Is there any way to apply from an "other.gradle" contained as a resource in a jar file pulled in as a dependency?