# Replace word in strings.xml with gradle for a buildType

Tags: android, gradle, preprocessor

I have a project which has multiple localizations.
Now I have to replace a certain word in all `strings.xml` files for different buildTypes. For example let's say I have this:

```
<string>My name is Bill</string>
<string>Bill is on duty today</string>
```

And in another buildType I need to have

```
<string>My name is Will</string>
<string>Will is on duty today</string>
```

How can I do it (probably through Gradle)?

Comment: use flavors. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) through

Comment: `<string>My name is %s</string>` `<string>%s is on duty today</string>` ... `getString(id, "Bill");`

Comment: @Selvin, thanks, but I know about this way, and can't use this solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a *correct* solution, which is not a *workaround*:
For the required `buildType` add the following

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast {
        def dir = new File("${buildDir}/intermediates/res/merged/${variant.dirName}")  //iterating through resources, prepared for including to APK (merged resources)
        println("Resources dir " + dir)
        dir.eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if(file.name.endsWith(".xml")) { //processing only files, which names and with .xml
                String content = file.getText('UTF-8')
                if(content != null && content.contains("Bill")) {
                    println("Replacing name in " + file)
                    content = content.replace("Bill", "Will")  //replacing all Bill words with Will word in files
                    file.write(content, 'UTF-8')
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like following in build.gradle but would only apply to that particular string resource.

`resValue "string", "<string_name>", string_value`

Comment: that will require me to add all used `<string_name>` strings in config, right?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes, unfortunately so....it's also not possible to include reference to particular string resource in other string resources in strings.xml  (at least as partial component of string)

Comment: ok, thanks, but this solution would take too much time, and I know other much faster, but ugly solution to implement a TextView, which will replace any `Bill` word to `Will` word. But as said, it is ugly, and I'd prefer using some preprocessing on `strings.xml`

Answer (score 3):

The answers here no longer work with latest android build tools, but here is a new version that is working for me.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doFirst {
         variant.sourceSets.each { sourceSet ->
            sourceSet.res.srcDirs = sourceSet.res.srcDirs.collect { dir ->
                def relDir = relativePath(dir)
                copy {
                    from(dir)
                    include '**/*.xml'
                    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
                    filter {
                        line -> line
                                .replace('Bill', 'Will')
                    }
                    into("${buildDir}/tmp/${variant.dirName}/${relDir}")
                }
                copy {
                    from(dir)
                    exclude '**/*.xml'
                    into("${buildDir}/tmp/${variant.dirName}/${relDir}")
                }
                return "${buildDir}/tmp/${variant.dirName}/${relDir}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create file gradle.properties in directory with build.gradle of your app (module, not project). In this app place string like 
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = ishufhiaushdiasdh

add field 'buildConfigField' in your build.gradle file in buildTypes section. It will look like:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY", String.format("\"%s\"", GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY", String.format("\"%s\"", GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

After compiling project you'll find generated value as static String in BuildConfig class.

Comment: this way I'll be able to use this field in JAVA code, but not in strings.xml, right?

Comment: I currently use this approach for URLs too

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the dynamic string formatting:

```
<string name="my_message">%1$s is on duty today</string>
```

in one build variant:

```
<string name="name">Bill</string>
```

in another build variant:

```
<string name="name">Will</string>
```

in your code:

```
String text = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.my_message), getResources().getString(R.string.name));
```

Comment: I know about this solution, but I can't use it because it would take much time, and could produce errors in process of migration.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, though not applicable in all cases, is to use a `Copy` task with a `filter` directive :

```
task replace (type: Copy) {
   from "sources" {
      include "srcStrings.xml"
      filter { line -> line.replaceAll("Will", "Bill") }
   }
   into "strings.xml"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should observe the results obtained with `replace()` and `replaceAll()` when processing the lines. And take into account that the absolute directory of the file to be processed exists (not necessarily in res.srcDirs)

```
sourceSets {
    flavor {

        println res.srcDirs

        task testA() {

            def relativeDirFile = 'src/flavor/res'
            def file = "${relativeDirFile}/values/strings.xml"
            def absoluteDirFile = "${rootDir}/module/${file}"

            def buildDirToCopy = "${buildDir}/tmp/${relativeDirFile}/values"

            copy {
                    from(absoluteDirFile)
                    filter {
                        String line ->
                            println line

                            line.replace("(.*)", line)  // To keep the line
                            // OR
                            line.replaceAll("(.*)", "") // To erase the line
                    }
                    into(buildDirToCopy)
            }

            res.srcDirs += (buildDirToCopy + "/strings.xml")
            
            // Check the directories that were included in the flavor.
            println res.srcDirs
        }

    }
}
```

Finally you could [extract the task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27219662/5279996) into another gradle file

---

I also recommend deepening the use of [regex](https://regexr.com/).

GL