# Too many tasks in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle, devops, gradlew

I have around 25 tasks for various devops things as part of my large multiproject build.

The structure of the project looks like this

```
RootProject
  -buildSrc
  -DirectoryA
     -SubProjectA1
     -SubProjectA2
     -SubProjectA3
  -DirectoryB
     -SubProjectB1
     -SubProjectB2
  -DirectoryC
     -SubProjectC1
     -SubProjectC2
```

etc..

Directories are there just to conveniently separate projects. *RootProject* and all *SubProject* have *build.gradle* files.

In the RootProject build.gradle file there are around 25 tasks. 
These tasks are configured on both root project and subprojects.

They make *build.gradle* rather long and complicated. So I thought of moving them into separate *Tasks.gradle* file located under *buildSrc* directory. And then pulling them in with *"apply from"*

**Is this a good practice or is there a better way?**

If I pull them in, there is another issue. Some tasks are configured for *SubProjects*, and other are configured for *RootProject*. So I can't really just put them into single *Tasks.gradle* file.

**Should I then put them into something like** *RootProjectTasks.gradle* and *SubProjectsTasks.gradle*?

It all feels a little wrong...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to split/factor out common parts of Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566685/is-there-a-way-to-split-factor-out-common-parts-of-gradle-build)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins for build, then you should make **build.gradle** for **every sub-project** and also for Root Project.

In Jenkins, you can **Invoke Gradle script** multiple times.
So, you can invoke every build.gradle file one by one.

There is another way to invoke every build.gradle of sub-projects by invoking only Root projects build.gradle.
For that you must add following line in **settings.gradle**

***include ":sub-project1-name", ":sub-project2-name", ":sub-project3-name",***

Feel free for more information

Answer (score 0):

Do not put `*.gradle` file into the buildSrc folder. The buildSrc folder is a nested project folder that should be organized like a project and contain only `*.java` or `*.groovy` files in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`.

You can extract tasks into separate gradle files and include them via `apply from`.

Tasks that apply to all projects can go here:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

Tasks that apply only to all subprojects can go here:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

You can either also include them directly from the submodules that need them. Or apply to only some subprojects like so:

```
def clientProjects() {
    return subprojects.findAll {
            // some predicate that is true only for client projects
    }
}

configure(clientProjects()) {
    apply plugin: ...
}
```