# split large build.gradle to multiple files

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, swagger

In one of my gradle project build.gradle is having huge data, so it's getting difficult to maintain it. We are using yaml based approach to generate code using swagger codegen, because of this whenever a new service needs to be developed in the project requires new entries in the build.gradle.

Is there any possibility of splitting this build.gradle to multiple files, each one will have few service  entries like yaml, dependency etc , example 10 entries, after that for next 10 entries one more gradle file and finally a parent build.gradle to combine all these and execute final build, which can generate either single or multiple WAR files depending on configuration?

Example generate one war file out of build1.gradle,2nd war from build2.gradle etc and also single war for build1.gradle and build2.gradle based on some configuration, is this possible with gradle?

As this being existing code can't change the project structure and currently above said scenario is handled using ANT build with some scripting(shell).

Comment: does this solve your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566685/is-there-a-way-to-split-factor-out-common-parts-of-gradle-build ?

Comment: I will check this approach and update on the same, thank you