# How do you split large kotlin based Gradle build files with variables?

Tags: variables, gradle, kotlin-dsl

I have a large gradle.build.kts file and I'm trying to break it into smaller pieces using apply(from = "xxx") (I'm open to better solutions if one exists).

The problem is that I've run into a problem where one of my scripts cant handle variables.  Here is the sample code:

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins { java }
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies { testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12") }

println("Before Apply")
apply(from = "./build.gradle.test.kts")
println("After Apply")
```

build.gradle.test.kts

```kotlin
println("Applying")

tasks.test {
    val failedTests = mutableListOf<TestDescriptor>()
}

println("Applied")
```

both files are at the root project folder.

output...

```
>gradle clean build test

> Configure project :
Before Apply

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Users\jamesdmcmillian\Projects\FacilitatorLabs\Labs\gradle-dsl-script-variables\build.gradle.kts' line: 6

* What went wrong:
Could not open cp_dsl generic class cache for script 'D:\Users\jamesdmcmillian\Projects\FacilitatorLabs\Labs\gradle-dsl-script-variables\build.gradle.test.kts' (C:\Users\jamesdmcmillian\.gradle\caches\6.8\scripts\7kclhsg56vjpfm1z90j
4hwepn).
> Could not compile script 'D:\Users\jamesdmcmillian\Projects\FacilitatorLabs\Labs\gradle-dsl-script-variables\build.gradle.test.kts'.
   > startup failed:
     script 'D:\Users\jamesdmcmillian\Projects\FacilitatorLabs\Labs\gradle-dsl-script-variables\build.gradle.test.kts': 4: expecting '}', found 'failedTests' @ line 4, column 9.
            val failedTests = mutableListOf<TestDescriptor>()
                ^

     1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Is it possible to have variables/values contained inside applied scripts?
This seems like an awfully bad restriction if it's not.

These posts are close, but don't answer the variable question: [Is there a way to split/factor out common parts of Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566685/is-there-a-way-to-split-factor-out-common-parts-of-gradle-build)

Also, I've read the kotlin-dsl primer, and not seeing anything specific to this issue, or maybe i missed it.  The rest of the code works fine, so I've eliminated it from this question.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Versions Info:
Gradle 6.8
Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64