# Extract common methods from Gradle build script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build script (`build.gradle`), in which I created some tasks. These tasks consist mostly of method calls. The called methods are also in the build script.

Now, here's the situation:

I am creating a fair amount of build scripts, which contain different tasks, but utilise the same methods from the original script. Thus, I would like to extract these "common methods" in some way, so I can easily re-use them instead of copying them for each new script I create.

If Gradle were PHP, something like the following would be ideal:

```
//script content
...
require("common-methods.gradle");
...
//more script content
```

But of course, that isn't possible. Or is it?

Anyway, how can I achieve this result? What is the best possible method to do this?   I've read through the Gradle documentation already, but I can't seem to determine which method will be the easiest and best suited for this.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to extract the methods in another file

(using `apply from: 'common-methods.gradle'`),

so the structure is as follows:

```
parent/
      /build.gradle              // The original build script
      /common-methods.gradle     // The extracted methods
      /gradle.properties         // Properties used by the build script
```

After executing a task from `build.gradle`, I've bumped into a new problem: apparently, methods don't get recognized when they're in `common-methods.gradle`.

How can that be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure you need to be writing the methods at all ? You would miss out on some of the Gradle goodies if you write your build scripts in terms of methods, most importantly it will take extra work to get the incremental build to work correctly. The intended abstraction is to use and re-use [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html)s. You can also create [custom tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html). Perhaps you should consider putting the implementations you now have in methods into tasks.

Comment: @Alpar and _others_; what purpose is served making something like a `timestamp()` or `currentWorkingDirectory()` methods as _`task`_-s (for  example).  Utility functions and similar things are nominally scalar -- They wouldn't be tasks except that there are limitations on code-reuse in-built with Gradle and most build systems. I like the *DRY* world where I can make a thing ONE time and reuse it.  In fact, extending @Pieter VDE's example I also use a "`root.gradle`" pattern for my parent project -- The build.gradle file usually defines some project specifics and then just `apply ${ROOT}` ...

Comment: If you need a centralized way to work with properties maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251228/how-to-import-a-helper-class-in-buildsrc-build-gradle-kts-settings-gradle-kts/60270896#60270896

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It isn't possible to share methods, but you can share extra properties containing a closure, which boils down to the same thing. For example, declare `ext.foo = { ... }` in `common-methods.gradle`, use `apply from:` to apply the script, and then call the closure with `foo()`.

Comment: It does the trick indeed! But I do have a question about this: How about methods returning something? F.e. `File foo(String f)` will become `ext.foo = { f -> ... }`, can I then just do something like: `File f = foo(...)`?

Comment: Apparently, the question in my previous comment is possible. So thank you Peter, for answering this question!

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser  Why isn't it possible?  Gradle.org thinks otherwise: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_build

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky thanks for the link. I wonder how can I use a value generated in separate build file in the gradle.build - this way it would be very useful :)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky How should the link you shared help in the context of Peter VDEs question?

Comment: @t0r0X Look for word **shared**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky hmmm, ok, looks like you haven't completely read the question details. I thought there was some specialty I overlooked in the docs you linked. "build logic" != "methods/functions", but "tasks". So tasks are shared, but methods/functions not. Therefore the workarounds described by Peter and Matthias are needed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any idea how i could achieve something similar for kotlin but typesafe way? like dont guess the type of a function and extract it from ext, but instead import a class or kotlin object which already has all type information for its functions...

Comment: Note that the `ext.` prefix is not optional :) https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Answer (score 193):

Building on [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715137/extract-common-methods-from-gradle-build-script#18718802), this is how I export my methods:

Content of `helpers/common-methods.gradle`:

```java
// Define methods as usual
def commonMethod1(param) {
    return true
}
def commonMethod2(param) {
    return true
}

// Export methods by turning them into closures
ext {
    commonMethod1 = this.&commonMethod1
    otherNameForMethod2 = this.&commonMethod2
}
```

And this is how I use those methods in another script:

```java
// Use double-quotes, otherwise $ won't work
apply from: "$rootDir/helpers/common-methods.gradle"

// You can also use URLs
//apply from: "https://bitbucket.org/mb/build_scripts/raw/master/common-methods.gradle"

task myBuildTask {
    def myVar = commonMethod1("parameter1")
    otherNameForMethod2(myVar)
}
```

[Here's more](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-turn-methods-into.html) on converting methods to closures in Groovy.

Comment: is there any specific reason to use the closure name as ext?

Comment: @AnoopSS We add the two closures to [Gradle's extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html). These extra properties are bundled in an object called `ext`.

Comment: Can we, somehow, cast the value as a class of ours, which is defined in the included file?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to post a separate question with example code about this, @GarouDan.

Answer (score 13):

Using the **Kotlin DSL** it works like this:

**build.gradle.kts**:

```kotlin
apply {
  from("external.gradle.kts")
}

val foo = extra["foo"] as () -> Unit
foo()
```

**external.gradle.kts**:

```kotlin
extra["foo"] = fun() {
  println("Hello world!")
}
```

Comment: great is there a way to share the actuall type? you're basically loosing the type safety and compilers help... if you could share the class that contains your methods then you could make use of the compiler.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, I'm afraid... although I'm trying to call the function from inside another block, not at the root level. Claims the property on `extra` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a slight adjustment to [Matthias Braun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23290820/6706622),
in that instead of writing the same method-name twice and still have it
clear and consise, why not simply do the following:

```
ext.commonMethod1 = (param) -> {
    return true
} as Closure<boolean>
```

The usage of the `as`-operator simply tells one explicitly,
that this function will return a value of `boolean`-type.

Because after all, this still is Groovy goodness. Neat huh?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for Kotlin DSL could be:

**my-plugin.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
extra["sum"] = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }
```

**settings.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
@Suppress("unchecked_cast", "nothing_to_inline")
inline fun <T> uncheckedCast(target: Any?): T = target as T
    
apply("my-plugin.gradle.kts")
    
val sum = uncheckedCast<(Int, Int) -> Int>(extra["sum"])
    
println(sum(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plugin by using the [conventions pattern](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html).

By doing so, you can create a plugin that shares some functions. Here's an example:

`Versions.kt`

```kotlin
object Versions {

    inline fun Configuration.replace(replacement: Provider<MinimalExternalModuleDependency>, crossinline cause: () -> String? = { null }) {
        val dependency = replacement.get()
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            if(requested.group == dependency.group && requested.name == dependency.name) {
                useVersion(dependency.version!!)
                val because = cause.invoke()
                if (because != null) {
                    because(because)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And its usage:
`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import Versions.replace


configurations.all {
    replace(libs.jackson.core) { "Conflict resolution." }
    replace(libs.jackson.databind) { "The version of the compiler has a security issue associated with this dependency." }
    replace(libs.apache.commons.text) { "The version of the compiler has a security issue associated with this dependency." }
    replace(libs.apache.commons.lang) { "Conflict resolution." }
    replace(libs.slf4j.api) { "Conflict resolution." }
}
```