# How to define and call custom methods in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

As part of my project, I need to read files from a directory and do some operations all these in build script. For each file, the operation is the same(reading some SQL queries and execute it). I think its a repetitive task and better to write inside a method. Since I'm new to Gradle, I don't know how it should be. Please help.

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N1034A

Answer (score 140, accepted):

One approach given below:

```
ext.myMethod = { param1, param2 ->
    // Method body here
}
```

Note that this gets created for the project scope, ie. globally available for the project, which can be invoked as follows anywhere in the build script using `myMethod(p1, p2)` which is equivalent to `project.myMethod(p1, p2)`

The method can be defined under different scopes as well, such as within tasks:

```
task myTask {
    ext.myMethod = { param1, param2 ->
        // Method body here
    }

    doLast {
        myMethod(p1, p2) // This will resolve 'myMethod' defined in task
    }
}
```

Comment: One more doubt. Can I mark a method local to the task?. ext.myMethod  will mark it as global.

Comment: When we use `ext`, the scope is restricted to where it is defined, ie. if it is defined under a task, it is local to the task. The way it works is through entities (like project, task etc.) that implement [ExtensionAware](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtensionAware.html). This adds an [ExtraPropertiesExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) which is configured through the `ext` directive.

Comment: So that means I can use the same method name in different tasks without any conflict. ie; ext.myMethod in two or more tasks should work.

Comment: When accessing from a sub-project, can be accessed as rootProject.ext.myMethod(p1, p2)

Answer (score 46):

If you have a method in a different `.gradle` file, then defining it as `ext.method()` makes it accessible project wide so that it can be called by simply invoking it as `method()`. For example:

`versioning.gradle`:

```
// ext makes method callable project wide
ext.getVersionName = { ->
    try {
        def branchout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = branchout
        }
        def branch = branchout.toString().trim()

        if (branch.equals("master")) {
            def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            exec {
                commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
                standardOutput = stdout
            }
            return stdout.toString().trim()
        } else {
            return branch;
        }
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "$project.rootDir/versioning.gradle"
task showVersion << {
    // Use inherited method
    println 'VersionName: ' + getVersionName()
}
```

Without the `ext.method()` definition using `ext.`, the method will only be available within the `.gradle` file it is declared in. This is the same with properties.

Answer (score 31):

You can define methods in the following way:

```
// Define an extra property
ext.srcDirName = 'src/java'

// Define a method
def getSrcDir(project) {
    return project.file(srcDirName)
}
```

You can find more details in gradle documentation [Chapter 62. Organizing Build Logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html)

Comment: I tried this, however the method I am creating is executed on every task I am running, for example when trying to run ./gradlew clean - I see the method is being executed and this is not what I want - do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: @user1002065 hard to tell without seeing your setup, if you could please share (i.e. as a gist), then I could try to help

Answer (score 15):

An example with a root object containing methods.

hg.gradle file:

```
ext.hg = [

    cloneOrPull: { source, dest, branch ->
        if (!dest.isDirectory())
            hg.clone(source, dest, branch)
        else
            hg.pull(dest)
        hg.update(dest, branch)
    },

    clone: { source, dest, branch ->
        dest.mkdirs()
        exec {
            commandLine 'hg', 'clone', '--noupdate', source, dest.absolutePath
        }
    },

    pull: { dest ->
        exec {
            workingDir dest.absolutePath
            commandLine 'hg', 'pull'
        }
    },

]
```

build.gradle file

```
apply from: 'hg.gradle'

hg.clone('path/to/repo')
```

Answer (score 11):

Somehow, maybe because it's five years since the OP, but none of the

```
ext.someMethod = { foo ->
   methodBody
}
```

approaches are working for me. Instead, a simple function definition seems to be getting the job done in my gradle file:

```
def retrieveEnvvar(String envvar_name) {
    if ( System.getenv(envvar_name) == "" ) {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException("\n\n\nPlease specify environment variable ${envvar_name}\n")
    } else {
        return System.getenv(envvar_name)
    }       
}
```

And I call it elsewhere in my script with no prefix, ie `retrieveEnvvar("APP_PASSWORD")`

This is 2020 so I'm using Gradle 6.1.1.

Comment: I'm also on gradle 6.1.1, ex.someMethod = {} works fine. Just that I could not use param names while calling the lambda.

Comment: Sure, that works, but your method only exists within that script. So when you need the same functionality in two places, it unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: How do you reach this function inside the settings.gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

@ether_joe the top-voted answer by @InvisibleArrow above *does* work however you must define the method you call *before* you call it - i.e. earlier in the `build.gradle` file.

You can see an example [here](https://technicles.com/how-to-write-and-call-methods-in-gradle-script/).   I have used this approach with Gradle 6.5 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

With [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**) you can define regular functions and use them.
It doesn't matter whether you define your function before the call site or after it.

```kotlin
println(generateString())

fun generateString(): String {
    return "Black Forest"
}

tasks.create("MyTask") {
    println(generateString())
}
```

If you want to import and use a function from another script, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139585/8583692) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252724/8583692).

Answer (score 1):

In my react-native in build.gradle

```
def func_abc(y){return "abc"+y;}
```

then

```
def x = func_abc("y");
```

If you want to check:

```
throw new GradleException("x="+x);
```

or

```
println "x="+x;
```