# How to define a helper method for gradle repository?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle scripts have shortcut functions to define common well known repositories, for example

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I would like to define my own shortcut function something like `myPrivateMavenRepo()` so that I can write something like

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    myPrivateMavenRepo()
}
```

Rather than

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

Questions:

- How can a custom repo function be developed?
- Where is this custom function hosted?
- I have lots of repos that I want to switch to gradle I don't want to hardcode each build.gradle file with the repo Url how do I centralize this in a way that is easy to bootstrap?

Comment: Probabaly you are looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777591/how-to-define-and-call-custom-methods-in-build-gradle

Answer (score 3):

The methods in the `repositories` closure are defined by the [`RepositoryHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html) interface. While `mavenCentral()`, `mavenLocal()` and `jcenter()` add predefined repositories, all other methods require a configuration closure, action or map, which will be applied to a new [`ArtifactRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/ArtifactRepository.html).

A simple approach would be to define such configuration closures, actions or maps and provide them via a plugin extension:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven myPluginExtension.myRepoClosure
}
```

Since `RepositoryHandler` is also a [`ArtifactRepositoryContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ArtifactRepositoryContainer.html), you could use its modification methods like `add` directly to create and register `ArtifactRepository` objects:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    add myPluginExtension.myRepo
}
```

If you want to add methods directly to the `RepositoryHandler`, you can [alter its meta class](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/11/groovy-goodness-add-methods-dynamically.html). Please note that this is a Groovy feature, so you can only use this in a Groovy plugin, not a Java plugin.

```
project.repositories.metaClass.myRepo {
    // implement logic to add repository (e.g. call maven(closure) ...)
}
```

The method will be available in your build script:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    myRepo()
}
```

Comment: Either way fails with: "`Could not find method myRepo() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.`" message.

Comment: At least if 1. Put in separate file, 2. and imported like "`apply from: './my-repo.gradle'`" 3. finally, used like "`allprojects {        
       repositories {                                                                  
        myRepo()
    } }`"

Answer (score 3):

I think you could likely do

```
allprojects {
    repositories.ext.myPrivateMavenRepo = {
        repositories.maven {
           url: 'http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2'
       } 
    } 
}
```

Usage

```
repositories {
    myPrivateMavenRepo() 
}
```

You could easily turn that into a plugin