# Avoid code duplication - How to create functions (and call them) in gradle?

Tags: android, function, gradle, build, call

I've been looking for a few minutes over the internet on how to create functions and call them inside `build.gradle` without success. Since I found nothing I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right concept-keywords or if that's even possible.

I have two `buildTypes`:

```
release {

}

debug {

}
```

And I woud like to call this `snippet()` below inside both of them without duplicating it, or in other words, to create a function:

```
def propsFile = rootProject.file('properties')
            def M_PROP = "mProp"

            if (propsFile.exists()) {
                //Math
            }
```

Generating something like:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
              snippet()
            }
        }

        debug {
              snippet()
        }
    }
```

is that possible and how am I able to do this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777591/how-to-define-and-call-custom-methods-in-build-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
buildTypes {
   [release, debug].each { buildType ->
      if (foo) {
          buildType.doStuff()
      }
   }
}
```

Or maybe

```
ext.snippet = { buildType -> 
    if (foo) {
       buildType.doStuff()
    }
}
buildTypes {
    snippet(release)
    snippet(debug)
}
```

Note: There's also the [with { ... }](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/groovy-goodness-with-method.html) method in groovy so

```
buildType.doStuff1()
buildType.doStuff2()
buildType.doStuff3()
```

can be written as

```
buildType.with {
    doStuff1()
    doStuff2()
    doStuff3()
}
```