# How to assign API key in manifest from Constant Value class?

Tags: java, android, manifest

I am trying to assign value to below meta in manifest.

currently i have assign value from string.xml class.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value= "@string/MAPS_API_KEY" />
```

But I want Some thing like this..

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value= com.packagename.MyConstantInterface.MAPS_API_KEY />
```

I have search a lot, but haven't find a good solution.

**NOTE: I am getting all APIs keys from server, storing keys in snappy db and then assigning keys from snappy db to MyConstantInterface.**

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1: Create a file named secrets.properties in the main folder (i.e below local.properties, app, build, gradle, README.md,etc.

STEP 2: Paste your API Key in secrets.properties (i.e GOOGLE_API_KEY, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, etc)

STEP 3: Sync the project or Rebuild.
STEP 4: Open build.gradle (app) and create a def function to access the key declared in the secrets.properties.

```
def getApiKey(){
  def Properties props = new Properties()
  props.load(new FileInputStream(new File('secrets.properties')))
  return props['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']
}
```

STEP 5: Create a variable for the function getApiKey() in defaultConfig using manifestPlaceholders to use it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
defaultConfig {
    defaultPublishConfig 'debug'
    applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1000
    versionName '0.1.0'
    manifestPlaceholders = [ GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY:getApiKey()]
}
```

You’re good to go. Now GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY variable is public and can be used in AndroidManifest.xml like below

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

> manifestPlaceholders — It helps to create a global variable that can be used only in AndroidManifest.xml

```
buildTypes {
  release {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    , 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

  
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"
      , "\""+getApiKey()+"\""
  }
}
```

And, you can use GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY in Java or Kotlin classes like

```
BuildConfig.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
```

> Finally, don’t forget to add secrets.properties to your .gitignore file.

Solution was gotten from [This Medium post](https://medium.com/@takeoffandroid/securing-api-key-in-android-without-pushing-to-remote-repository-git-4237db104d91) by Chandrasekar Kappusamy

Comment: Great answer! But in fact you should use `props.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file('app.properties')))` for the file to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not simply use a java variable.

Instead of it, You need to inject build variables into the manifest

**Declaration:**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [MAPS_API_KEY_FOR_MANIFEST: "your_maps_key_here"] // TO use in manifest file
    buildConfigField "String", "MAPS_API_KEY", '"your_maps_key_here"' // TO use in java file
}
```

**Use in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value= "${MAPS_API_KEY_FOR_MANIFEST}" />
```

**Java file Usage:**

```
BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY
```

For more information, You can have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) and [this.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code)

Comment: thanks for quick answer. 
"your_maps_key_here" how can i get value from MyConstantInterface here?

Comment: No need to use your api-key from *MyConstantInterface*

Comment: i am getting API key from server. so how can i get that API key here?

Comment: Okay. I haven't do that but you can have a look [at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27777591/2289835)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question