# How to move a gradle function from build.gradle into a plugin?

Tags: gradle

Currently, I have a few utility functions defined in the top level build.gradle in a multi-project setup, for example like this:

```
def utilityMethod() {
    doSomethingWith(project) // project is magically defined
}
```

I would like to move this code into a plugin, which will make the utilityMethod available within a project that applies the plugin. How do I do that? Is it a project.extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are not meant to provide common methods but *tasks*.

When it comes to extensions they should be used to gather input for the applied plugins:

> Most plugins need to obtain some configuration from the build script.
>   One method for doing this is to use extension objects.

More details [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N16BD6).

Have a look at Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715137/extract-common-methods-from-gradle-build-script), using closures carried via `ext` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That actually does provide a way to go. The reason I want the method to be in the plugin is because it appears that's the only way I can access the project object, which sadly becomes unavailable if I don't define the function in the build.gradle itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184282/how-can-i-override-a-gradle-api-method why I'm exploring this...

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work using:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class FooPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.extensions.create("foo", FooExtension)
        target.task('sometask', type: GreetingTask)
    }
}
class FooExtension{
    def sayHello(String text) {
        println "Hello " + text
    }
}
```

Then in the client build.gradle file you can do this:

```
task HelloTask << {
    foo.sayHello("DOM")
}

c:\plugintest>gradle -q HelloTask
Hello DOM
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Comment: This approach hasn't worked for me with Gradle 4.4.  the `<<` is deprecated, so I used `.doFirst()` as well as declare the `HelloTask(){...}` itself.  Then things worked. :)  However, if plug-ins are not the _happy_ mechanism to provide common methods -- What is the way to provide reusable build tooling using Gradle?!

Answer (score 3):

I implemented this recently, a full example is available at [Github](https://github.com/eaaltonen/gradle_plugin_function_export).

The injection basically boils down to

```
target.ext.utilityMethod = SomeClass.&utilityMethod
```

**Beware:**
This method could potentially conflict with some other plugin, so you should consider whether to use **static imports** instead.

Based on [Answer 23290820](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23290820/1119345).