# How can I override a gradle api method?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to modify the way gradle resolves project dependencies. The way I currently do it is that I define a new method `smartProject()` which has the same signature as the `project()` method used in a dependency section:

```
dependencies {
    compile smartProject(path: ":some:other:project", configuration: "archives")
    ...
}
```

I would like to override `project()` so it magically works without having to edit every single build.gradle file in the system,

Comment: I believe the best way of doing this would be to write a plugin that manipulates the dependencies when applied. Changing core gradle behaviour feels like a mistake

Comment: Ok, that's fair... how would I hook into the right place of the configuration lifecycle where I could traverse the dependency structure and modify it?

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594625/gradle-custom-plugin-add-dependency-from-extension-object