# Same credentials for all repositories in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Please, help me to find the best solution for my problem:

In private LAN-network I have nexus repositories, and i need to use one user for getting access to repos.

The simplest solution is to add user and password to `gradle.properties` file and in every `build.gradle` file and every repo write the same code:

```
maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url 'https://maven.yourcorp1.net/'
   }

maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url 'https://maven.yourcorp2.net/'
   }
```

Where mavenUser and mavenPassword in `gradle.properties` are the same for all repositories:

```
mavenUser=admin
mavenPassword=admin123
```

It's all good and works fine, but there is  a lot of duplicate code.

Maybe you know - how in one place set same credentials for all maven repositories? I don't want to copy the same code for all repositories.

Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try finding the common part of all your repositories URL and use something like that :

```
['yourcorp1', 'yourcorp2'].each {
    maven {
         credentials {
             username "$mavenUser"
             password "$mavenPassword" 
        }
        url "https://maven.${it}.net/"
    } 
}
```

If they are many Gradle files, put it in a `repositories.gradle` file and use the [include directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590264/2003986).

Answer (score 1):

one can add Maven server settings into `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<settings>
   <servers>
    <server>
        <id>yourcorp1</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>yourcorp2</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    ...
    </servers>
</settings>
```

while Gradle requires plugins `maven-publish` and `maven-publish-auth`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish-auth'
```

and one has to assign unique names to the repositories:

```
maven {
    name: 'yourcorp1'
    url 'https://maven.yourcorp1.net/'
}

maven {
    name: 'yourcorp2'
    url 'https://maven.yourcorp2.net/'
}
```

alike this, there is little chance to check in confidential information ...