# Run a file mytask.gradle before executing assembleDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

How to run a Gradle task in a separate .gradle file before executing the assembleDebug task?

I have **build.gradle** (Project: gradle)

```
    buildscript {
//something
}

allprojects{
    //something
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn mytask
    }
}
```

And **mytask.gradle** including

```
task mytask << {
    println "mytask run!"
}
```

I have an exception: `Could not get unknown property 'mytask' for root project 'gradle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Do you include your "mytask.gradle" script in your main "build.gradle" script? ( in "build.gradle" :  `apply from : "./mytask.gradle"` )

Comment: In your **build.gradle** include this line  **apply from: 'gradle/mytask.gradle'** see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265283/how-can-i-import-one-gradle-script-into-another)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thank u, it works for me.